# A conditional sum of numbers in an array (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays

So the question says:
Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 7 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 7). Return 0 for no numbers. 
eg:

```
sum67({1, 2, 2}) → 5
sum67({1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7}) → 5
sum67({1, 1, 6, 7, 2}) → 4
```

My attempt:

```
public int sum67(int[] nums) {
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    if(nums[i] == 6){
      while(nums[i] == 7){
        i++;
      }
    }
    else{
      sum = sum + nums[i];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: While condition should be looking for !=7 for your requirement. Update while condition with       while(nums[i] != 7) and verify

Comment: `==` means equal, `!=` means not equal. Read the question again, look at your code, and you'll immediately see your problem.

Comment: Oh! Actually, the above code compiled but the tests didn't pass, so was wondering where exactly did I go wrong. Anyway, now figured it out. Also, thanks for the answer.

Comment: The compiler doesn't predict your desired output :)

Comment: Really? My whole life was a lie :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop never runs, because `n[i]` is six:

```
while(nums[i] == 7){
    i++;
}
```

it should be

```
while(nums[i] != 7){
    i++;
}
```

There is a way to avoid that inner loop, and solve the problem with a single loop, like this:

```
boolean seenSix = false;
for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    if (!seenSix) {
        if(nums[i] != 6) {
            sum[i] += n[i];
        } else {
            seenSix = true;
        }
    } else {
        seenSix = (n[i] != 7);
    }
}
```

Comment: Kudos! http://imgur.com/5q0LkJT

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint. The following isn't quite right:

```
  while(nums[i] == 7){
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
while(nums[i] != 7){
    i++;
}
```